# Unity game crash on some Android 6 (API 23)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins

We have recently launched our android game ^_^ It it working fine for all users **except for a few**.

The has complained that it **suddenly crashes in-game**. We couldn't track or reproduce the issue but we know that they all have the same android version which is **Android 6, API 23**.

We tried running it on android 6 devices in our company but it just works fine.

I suspect it has something to do with something's version.

Any sort of idea?

> Unity version: 5.4.1f1
>
> Minimum API level in Player Settings: API 9
>
> Target SDK version: API 24

### Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="ir.funera.crazycrowz" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.farsitel.bazaar.permission.PAY_THROUGH_BAZAAR" />
  <!-- TODO: Replace the 'package' value above to reflect your app's package id. -->
  <!-- NOTE: Adjust minSDKVersion and targetSdkVersion as desired. -->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
  <!-- NOTE: You must have at least these four permissions for AdColony. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.soomla.SoomlaApp">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <!-- <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" /> -->
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <!-- NOTE: You must include these three activity specifications for AdColony. -->
    <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyOverlay" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.soomla.store.billing.bazaar.BazaarIabService$IabActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <meta-data android:name="billing.service" android:value="bazaar.BazaarIabService" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

### Here is the list of plugins used in this game with their versions:

[image]

### Here is all the installed packages in android SDK:

[image]

Comment: The more plugins you use in Unity, the more likely you will have these  crashing problems. I suggest you get the Android crash log from your clients. Without it, you won't be able to fix this.

Comment: We tried contacting them but unfortunately none of them has replied yet. they just gave a heart breaking 1 star vote and deleted the app!

Comment: Most clients don't care about reporting a crash. That's up to you find out what's going on. You can get crash reports from [Fabric](http://fabric.io/blog/introducing-fabric-for-unity/), or Unity's built in [analytics](https://unity3d.com/services/analytics).

Comment: thanks. good guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe we missed this!

In android versions other than 6 it asks for permissions **before install** and just doesn't install if user does not want to grant.
But android 6 asks for permissions **after user runs the app**.

Some users think they know better and don't grant permission! The app starts without some of the required permissions and it crashes eventually.

The solution would be to double check permissions in game and handle it before it crashes.